# is there a way to load large data using jqGrid without pagination

Tags: javascript, pagination, jqgrid, loading, bulkinsert

I'm trying to load large data(at least 5000 rows) using jqGrid without pagination. I tried some ways that already posted here but it didn't work for me. the conditions are: no pagination, at least 5000 rows, over 15 columns, some of editable columns like input box, combos.
when the rows over even 1000, it makes feel slow and stutter. Please help...
my code:

```
function getTable1_init() {

    let tbl_1_title = ['의뢰번호', '기호', '소재지', '지번', '지목', '공부면적 (㎡)', '이용상황', '용도지역1', '용도지역2', '도로교통', '형상', '지세', '방위', '용도지역1 면적', '용도지역2 면적', '용도지대', '개별공지시가(원/㎡)', '공시년도', '표준지일련번호', '표준지소재지지번', '용도지구', '계획시설', '저촉률', '제한구역기타', '농지구분', '임야', '철도', '폐기물', '전년지가', '상승률', '2년전지가', 'PNUCode','','법원경매 참고데이터', '표준지2개이상', '불법형질변경', '미불용지', '사용료', '환매토지'];

    tbl_1_columns = ['SerialNo', 'NumericNo', 'LandLocation', 'LandAddress', 'LandCategory', 'PubLedgerArea', 'UseSituation', 'UseAreaOne', 'UseAreaTwo',
        'RoadTraffic', 'LandTrend', 'Direction', 'quarter', 'UseAreaOneArea', 'UseAreaTwoArea', 'UseBelt', 'IndiDeclaredLandVal', 'StandardArea_Serial',
        'StandardArea_Address', 'UseDistrict', 'PlanningFacility', 'ConflictRate', 'RestrictedAreaETC', 'FarmType', 'Forest', 'Railroad',
        'Waste', 'LandPrice_Lastyear', 'Growthrate', 'LandPrice_TwoYearAgo']

    tbl_1.jqGrid({
        styleUI : 'Bootstrap',
        iconSet : 'Octicons',
        datatype: 'local',
        data: [],
        //url: data_src_url,
        //datatype: 'jsonstring',
        //datastr: tbl_1_data,
        width: 'auto',
        height: 'auto',
        colNames: tbl_1_title,
        colModel: [
          { name: 'SerialNo', index: 'SerialNo', align: "center",sortable: true, width: 80, hidden: true },
          { name: 'NumericNo', index: 'NumericNo', template: "numberStr", sorttype: "number", align: "center", width: 60 },
          { name: 'LandLocation', index: 'LandLocation', align: "center",sortable: false, width: 200 },
          { name: 'LandAddress', index: 'LandAddress', align: "center",sortable: false, width: 100 },

          { name: 'LandCategory', index: 'LandCategory', align: "center", sortable: false, editable: true, width: 60 ,edittype: "text", editoptions: { value: landCategoryCombosData } },
          { name: 'PubLedgerArea', index: 'PubLedgerArea', template: "numberStr", align: "center", sortable: false, editable: true, width: 120 },
          { name: 'UseSituation', index: 'UseSituation', align: "center", sortable: false, editable: true, width: 150 ,edittype: "text", editoptions: { value: UseSituationCombosData } },
          { name: 'UseAreaOne', index: 'UseAreaOne', align: "center" ,template: "numberStr", sortable: false, editable: true, width: 100 ,edittype: "text", editoptions: { value: UseAreaCombosData } },
          { name: 'UseAreaTwo', index: 'UseAreaTwo', align: "center" ,template: "numberStr", sortable: false, editable: true, width: 100 ,edittype: "text", editoptions: { value: UseAreaCombosData } },

          { name: 'RoadTraffic', index: 'RoadTraffic', align: "center", sortable: false, editable: true, width: 200 ,edittype: "text", editoptions: { value: RoadTrafficCombosData } },
          { name: 'Shape', index: 'Shape', align: "center", sortable: false, editable: true, width: 120 ,edittype: "text", editoptions: { value: ShapeCombosData } },
          { name: 'LandTrend', index: 'LandTrend', align: "center", sortable: false, editable: true, width: 100 ,edittype: "text", editoptions: { value: LandTrendCombosData } },
          { name: 'Direction', index: 'Direction', align: "center", sortable: false, editable: true, width: 60 ,edittype: "text", editoptions: { value: "1:동;2:서;3:남;4:북;-1:없음" } },
          { name: 'UseAreaOneArea', index: 'UseAreaOneArea', align: "center" , template: "numberStr", sortable: false, editable: true, width: 130 },
          { name: 'UseAreaTwoArea', index: 'UseAreaTwoArea', align: "center" , template: "numberStr", sortable: false, editable: true, width: 130 },
          { name: 'UseBelt', index: 'UseBelt', align: "center", sortable: false, editable: true, width: 160, edittype: "text", editoptions: { value: "1:주택지대;2:공업지대;3:농경지대(전지대);4:농경지대(답지대);5:임야지대;6:택지후보지지대;7:상업지대;-1:없음" } },

          { name: 'IndiDeclaredLandVal', index: 'IndiDeclaredLandVal', align: "center", sortable: false, editable: true, width: 160 },
          { name: 'Year', index: 'Year', align: "center", sortable: false, editable: true, width: 80 },
          { name: 'StandardArea_Serial', index: 'StandardArea_Serial', align: "center", sortable: false, editable: true, width: 130 },
          { name: 'SAreaAddress', index: 'SAreaAddress', align: "center", sortable: false, editable: true, width: 150 },
          { name: 'UseDistrict', index: 'UseDistrict', align: "center", sortable: false, editable: true, width: 80 },
          { name: 'PlanningFacility', index: 'PlanningFacility', align: "center", sortable: false, editable: true, width: 80 },
          { name: 'ConflictRate', index: 'ConflictRate', align: "center", sortable: false, editable: true, width: 80 },
          { name: 'RestrictedAreaETC', index: 'RestrictedAreaETC', align: "center", sortable: false, editable: true, width: 120 },
          { name: 'FarmType', index: 'FarmType', align: "center", sortable: false, editable: true, width: 80 },
          { name: 'Forest', index: 'Forest', align: "center", sortable: false, editable: true, width: 70 },
          { name: 'Railroad', index: 'Railroad', align: "center", sortable: false, editable: true, width: 70 },
          { name: 'Waste', index: 'Waste', align: "center", sortable: false, editable: true, width: 70 },
          { name: 'LandPrice_Lastyear', index: 'LandPrice_Lastyear', align: "center", sortable: false, editable: true, width: 80 },
          { name: 'Growthrate', index: 'Growthrate', align: "center", sortable: false, editable: true, width: 70 },
          { name: 'LandPrice_TwoYearAgo', index: 'LandPrice_TwoYearAgo', align: "center", sortable: false, editable: true, width: 90 },
          { name: 'PNUCode', index: 'PNUCode', align: "center", sortable: false, hidden: true},
          { name: 'Remarks', index: 'Remarks', align: "center", sortable: false, hidden: true},
          { name: 'insertInput', index: 'insertInput', align:"center", editable: false, width: 200, formatter: function(cellValue, options, rowObject){
                let obj = {};
                obj.options = options;
                obj.rowObject = rowObject;
                let literalObj = JSON.stringify(obj);
                let btn = `<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick='courtReferenceDataLand(${literalObj})'>참고</button>`;
                return btn;
            } },
            { name: 'GROUP1', hidden: true, formatter: function(value, option, row) {
                switch(value) {
                case 1: return true;
                case 0: return false;
                case true: return true;
                case false: return false;
                default: return value;
                }
            } },
            { name: 'GROUP2', hidden: true, formatter: function(value, option, row) {
                switch(value) {
                case 1: return true;
                case 0: return false;
                case true: return true;
                case false: return false;
                default: return value;
                }
            } },
            { name: 'GROUP3', hidden: true, formatter: function(value, option, row) {
                switch(value) {
                case 1: return true;
                case 0: return false;
                case true: return true;
                case false: return false;
                default: return value;
                }
            } },
            { name: 'GROUP4', hidden: true, formatter: function(value, option, row) {
                switch(value) {
                case 1: return true;
                case 0: return false;
                case true: return true;
                case false: return false;
                default: return value;
                }
            } },
            { name: 'GROUP5', hidden: true, formatter: function(value, option, row) {
                switch(value) {
                case 1: return true;
                case 0: return false;
                case true: return true;
                case false: return false;
                default: return value;
                }
            } },
        ],
        sortname: 'NumericNo',
        sortorder: "asc",
        rowNum: 9999999,
        multiselect: true,
        async:false,
        pager: '#pager_jqgrid1',
        loadonce: true,
        cellsubmit: 'clientArray'
      });
      tbl_1.jqGrid('bindKeys', true);
      getTable1_refresh();
}
```

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used? 5000 rows with 15 columns if too much. In all cases you will have problems.

Comment: jqGrid JS - v5.3.2. loading takes about few seconds but the scroll is really stutter.

Comment: Since you use the commercial version I recommend you to contact our support team, but really I do not see how to optimize this. Just to compare you can use another grid with the same amount of data loaded locally and you will see that the behavior will be the same.